# How to stop the .on("scroll") from firing once its requirements have been met?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function:

When I call the function, it passes the position of a div as a parameter. When the position is saved, **if I scroll 20 pixels up OR down from that div's position**, the requirements are met. How can I stop the scrolling listener from listening to my scrolling once the requirements have been met?

As you can see, I've tried returning, and unbinding.

```
      function checkScroll(position) { //Check if user has scroller
        $(document).bind("scroll", function() { //Document on scroll
           if (($(window).scrollTop() < (position - 20)) || ($(window).scrollTop() > (position + 20))) {
              console.log("Requirements met. Stopping scrolling listener now.");

              return; //PREFERABLY, STOP THE SCROLLING EVENT FROM FIRING
              $(document).unbind("scroll"); //Attempt #2
              $(window).unbind("scroll"); // Attempt #3
           }
        });
      }
```

Can someone guide me to the right direction please?
Thank you.

Comment: `$(document).unbind("scroll");` should work, but of course you have to remove the `return` statement (everything after the `return` statement is not executed).

Comment: @FelixKling thanks! I had it right under my nose this entire time.

Comment: Don't they have on and off methods now instead of bind?

Comment: I would like to know this ^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I had to do:

Remove the following line:

```
return;
```

That way it could get to the actual unbinding part of it. Which is this:

```
$(document).unbind("scroll");
```

The code would look like this:

```
  function checkScroll(position) { //Check if user has scroller
    $(document).bind("scroll", function() { //Document on scroll
       if (($(window).scrollTop() < (position - 20)) || ($(window).scrollTop() > (position + 20))) {
          console.log("Requirements met. Stopping scrolling listener now.");
          $(document).unbind("scroll");
       }
    });
  }
```